# iPhone mobile number using Core telephony

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number, core-telephony

As far as my understanding, there is no public API available in iPhone SDK to find the users mobile number.

Can we find the mobile number of iPhone user using the Core telephony framework added in 4.0 SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the CoreTelephony framework provides some basic information about the carrier and limited info about calls, not much else.

The limited information includes things like the amount of current active calls, the call ID (not a mobile number, just a unique ID that the OS uses to track the particular call) and the state of a call, like whether the call is on hold or not.

The main feature in CallTelephony is an API to check whether or not a carrier allows VoIP over 3G.

Comment: is the call id goves by iphone os is same for same user or it chooses id randomly?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no correlation between user and ID. The ID simply identifies one call amongst many. If the same person calls again, I'm pretty sure they'll get a new ID. The ID is unique to the call, not to the user/person.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can, but it's tricky. It involves using **iOS private API, which will determine Apple to reject your app in case you want to post it on the App Store.**

Here's what I did:

1. download and install the class-dump utility:
   http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/
2. in the command line go to this folder:
   */Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework*
   and perform the following command:

   > class-dump CoreTelephony > CoreTelephony.h

   This will create a header file in the current directory. Move this
   file in the desired directory.
3. in your Xcode project, import the CoreTelephony.framework (Xcode 4:
   click on the project target -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binary With
   Libraries -> + -> select the CoreTelephony.framework in the iOS list
   -> click Add)
4. import the CoreTelephony.h file using the same method as above Xcode
   4: click on the project target -> Build Phases tab -> Link Binary
   With Libraries -> + -> Add Other -> select your file in the Finder)
5. at the end of the CoreTelephony.h file, add the following:

   ```
   extern NSString *CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber();
   ```
6. import the CoreTelephony.h in your code and call the above function.
7. when building the project, you may find that there are compilation
   errors in the CoreTelephony.h - usually an interface declaration
   that needs to be moved before another interface declaration or
   protocol sequences written incorrectly
8. in case you have linking errors, use the following linking flags in
   the build settings of your project target:

   ```
   -force_flat_namespace 
   -undefined suppress
   ```

   (Xcode 4: click on the project target -> Build Settings tab -> Linking -> double-click on the values section
   of the *Other Linker Flags* property -> + -> add flags above -> Done
9. by now you should be able to get that phone number :)

Comment: Since I can't add more than 2 links in a post, due to my current status, please see this post for more useful links: [http://www.hackint0sh.org/f9/57803.htm#post936233]

Comment: just for the record, you don't need to include the CoreTelephony.h file to the project, just add extern declaration.

Comment: This works brilliantly.  Simply add extern NSString *CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber(); to your class and call it.  Oh, and don't submit to the store with that call, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to get cell phone number from call log then see this link it may be helpful. But i am not sure that after using this apple will aprove ur app.
[call details](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)