# Are there new API's in the iPhone SDK which allow you to access the iPhone's Call log (Like Agile Reply in the App Store)?

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-telephony

I saw a new app called [Agile Reply](http://itunes.apple.com/app/agile-reply/id416445913?mt=8) which allows you to send a sms to the person whom just called you. I didn't buy the app but I don't understand how it would work since as far as I know you can't access the call log through the official iPhone SDK. So my main question is:

**Are there new API's in the iPhone SDK which allow you to access the iPhone's Call log?**

I know there are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/accessing-the-iphones-call-log-with-the-iphone-sdk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615240/accessing-call-log-history-in-iphone) however I didn't know if I should hijack those or start a new one.

Comment: With regards to your other questions, you will get an answer for those at http://meta.stackoverflow.com . Also, Agile Reply couldn't be found on the iTunes store in my region. Is it only available in certain regions?

Comment: Seems like Agile Reply was updated to version 1.1 on 2 March 2011, but is currently removed from App Store. Was wondering, too, how does it get last missed/declined phone number. Private APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here but it doesn't work for iOS5.

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CoreTelephony. While it won't give you arbitrary access to call logs, you can get notifications of call transitions, which if you can keep at least in the suspended state, may be enough. I don't know how accurate Agile Reply is.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407556/iphone-mobile-number-using-core-telephony CoreTelephoney gives you an unique id that is not related to the phone number.