# Is it possible to detect LTE connection using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, wireless, 3g, connectivity

I'm using the reachability API to detect my current connection, but I can only distinguish between WIFI and 3G.

I get the following flags:

LTE: `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsLocalAddress|kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN|kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection|kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable`

WIFI: `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect|kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable`

The problem is that LTE returns the same flags as a 3G connection. Is there any way to determine whether the user currently has LTE or 3G?

Comment: Are you interested in the higher bandwidth that comes with the network or just the type of network itself? There is a workaround for the former, but not the latter.

Comment: I guess the workaround is to simply try to download something and track the speed?

Answer (score 15):

As of iOS 7, you can find this out using the `currentRadioAccessTechnology` property of `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` in the CoreTelephony framework.

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];

if ([networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know why there is no documentation on the `currentRadioAccessTechnology` method?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This method added iOS7.0 but It wasn't add documents.
check the header file "CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h"
```oc
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString* currentRadioAccessTechnology __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
```

Comment: This still is not formally documented which makes me nervous. I put it in a try catch so that I can have some default behavior if it gets taken away.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if this hidden Core Telephony API can provide you with enough info for you to determine whether you're attached to an LTE or a slower technology.

```
CTRegistrationGetCurrentMaxAllowedDataRate();
```

It might be worth experimenting with.

More about using private APIs here: [iPhone mobile number using Core telephony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407556/iphone-mobile-number-using-core-telephony/9191683#9191683)

However, I've read that your app will be rejected by apple if you use private APIs.