# Is there any way to know what network an iPhone is connected to (LTE vs GSM)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, reachability, lte

With the release of iOS 6 and iphone 5 I'm trying to figure out how my app can know if the phone is in LTE mode vs GSM mode.

I haven't seen any updates to the Reachability API which can give whether it is connected to Wifi vs WWAN but I need to know what kind of WWAN connection it is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iO6 and below, you can not do this.

I have [asked this question](https://devforums.apple.com/message/735047) on the Apple developer forums, and Apple confirmed they do not yet have this functionality.

You can file a [feature request bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).  I have already done this (#12375460), but the more duplicates there are the more chance it will get implemented.

Also this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159167/is-it-possible-to-detect-lte-connection-using-ios-sdk).

Comment: That's a real shame as it seems to be a common question online.  I will add a feature request as well to see if I can help push Apple to implement this.

Answer (score 7):

As of iOS 7, you can find this out using the `currentRadioAccessTechnology` property of `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` in the CoreTelephony framework.

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];

if ([networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this - I did find this API in iOS7 as well.  It's about time!

Comment: Does anyone know why there is no documentation on the `currentRadioAccessTechnology` method?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Although this detects which radio access technology your device is capable of, it doesn't necessarily provide you with what it's currently using.  So if I have an iPhone capable of LTE, but I happen to be in an area with 3G data only, this code still reports LTE.